# How do you use cumulative frequency percentages to find percentiles?

Tags: statistics

I want to find the 25th, 50th, and 75th percentile of this data-set.

data-set:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTLwu.jpg

Am not sure how one uses the cumulative frequency percentage in order to derive what the 25th,50th, and 75th percentiles are.

I am guessing for the 50th, as I know this is generally the median, or middle number but I cannot be sure this is where 50% of the data clusters. But I would guess that p_50 = 36.6% and therefore would be on line 5.

So the median would be at 5 or at 36.6% with 605 cumulative frequency

Please help

Comment: This is the third time you have posted this question in the past hour.

Comment: @lulu could I at least get a hint in the right direction?

Comment: Hint: there are $1655$ people, total. What are 25%, 50%, and 75% of this number?

Comment: .25*1655 = 413.75______.50*1655=827.5_____.75*1655=1241.25

Comment: I think I figured it out. P_25 is at 5, P_50 is at 6, P_75 is at 7

Comment: @FooFighter I would post an answer. But since you haven´t finished your previous question it wouldn´t make sense. I would recommend to finish first a question and then post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always difficult to deal with an image that you have to leave
the main page to see.

Here is the main idea: In your data the lower quartile (25th percentile)
is at 5 because the cumulative percent for (up to and including) 4 is
19.8% < 25%, and the cumulative percent for 5 is 36.6% > 25%.

You can
use the same method to get the median (50th percentile) and the upper
quartile (75th percentile). The median is $6,$ as you say in a Comment.

Below I will show another dataset (generated using R statistical software)
and a summary that shows lower quartile, median, and upper quartile.
You can use this example to check whether you understand the fundamental
idea.

```
 x = sort(rbinom(60, 10, .7))
 x
 [1]  3  4  4  4  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6  6
[16]  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7
[31]  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
[46]  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9 10
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   3.00    6.00    7.00    7.05    8.00   10.00
```

The lower quartile is $6$ because six of 60 (10% < 25%) of observations
are at or below $5$. But 18 of 60 (30% > 25%) of observations are at or
below $6.$ Can you see how R computed the median and the upper quartile?

*Note:* You should know that various texts and statistical programs have
slightly different rules for defining percentiles. (Difficulties arise when
a percentile comes at a 'gap' between two values and when there are
very many tied values. Various sources deal with these difficulties in
different ways.) For large samples, these different methods give very
similar results.

Comment: So essentially the point at which right before it exceeds 25% and the point where it does exceed will be the point where it is the 25% percentile. Like you said since 19.9 < 25 but 36.6 > 25 we go with the upper-end? So we look at the two values which 25 falls bwtween, the lower end of 25 and the upper end of 25 and always go with the upper end?

Comment: Yes, upper end. You want to include the value that put the percentage 'over the target'. But various texts and software packages might show slightly different methods. Unlikely you will find differences for your dataset, but in general you need to know that there seems to be no universally accepted definition of quantiles. Discrepancies become unimplortant as sample size $n$ gets large.